# existing empty null variable in bash

Tags: bash, testing

I am using the code below to determine if a variable in bash exists, if it is empty, or if it has length>0. The code works, but I can't find a good explanation for how `if [ -n "${emptyvar+1}" ]` can detect if `emptyvar` is not set. If I remove the `+1` then the test fails for `""`. What is the purpose of the `+1` in the test?

```
#!/bin/bash

emptyvar="a"

if [ -n "${emptyvar+1}" ]
  then
    echo "emptyvar is defined"
    if [[ -z $emptyvar ]]
      then
         echo "emptyvar is empty"; 
      else
         echo "emptyvar is NOT empty"; 
        if [[ -n $emptyvar ]]
          then
             echo "emptyvar has length > 0"; 
          else
             echo "emptyvar has length 0"; 
        fi
    fi
  else
    echo "emptyvar is not defined"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `bash` documentation of [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${parameter:+word} If parameter is null or unset, nothing is
>   substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Omitting the colon (`:`) makes it test only if the variable is unset, rather than null or unset.

So `${emptyvar+1}` tests if `$emptyvar` is unset. If it is, it expands to the empty string; if not, it expands to `1`.

Comment: But why this `+1` is needed in OP's case since checking `[[ -n "$emptyvar" ]]` should also do the job.

Comment: That will not distinguish between a variable that's unset and a variable that's set to the empty string.

Comment: @anubhava See the third `if`, which uses that test.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create sets of functions to test a variable passed by its name:

```
function is_var_set {
    [[ -n ${!1+.} ]]
}

function is_var_empty {
    [[ -z ${!1} ]]
}
```

Test:

```
> A=''
> is_var_set A && echo "A is set." || echo "A is unset."
A is set.
> is_var_empty A && echo "A is empty." || echo "A is not empty."
A is empty.
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` 4.2 added a new test operator, `-v`, that tests if a variable has been set.

```
# -v takes the name of the variable, not its values (since you are
# testing if it has a value or not).
if [[ -v emptyvar ]]; then
    echo "emptyvar is defined"
    if [[ -z $emptyvar ]]
      then
         echo "emptyvar is empty"; 
      else
         echo "emptyvar is NOT empty"; 
    fi
  else
    echo "emptyvar is not defined"
fi
```

Note that an empty variable is one whose string has length 0, so your `-n` test is redundant.

Comment: I tested it on my mac and on Ubuntu 10.04 and got an error. Maybe they are not 4.2? Error: ./a.sh: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
./a.sh: line 5: syntax error near `emptyvar'
./a.sh: line 5: `if [[ -v emptyvar ]]; then'   Line 5 is if [[ -v emptyvar ]]; then

Comment: Check the value of `$BASH_VERSION`. Mac OS X ships with 3.2, and I suspect Ubuntu 10.04 ships with 4.1.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Mac is 3.2.51(1)-release and Ubuntu is 4.1.5(1)-release

Answer (score 0):

Another way to express it:

```
$ unset var
$ if [[ -z ${var+x} ]]; then echo unset; elif [[ -z $var ]]; then echo empty; else echo not empty; fi
unset
$ var=
$ if [[ -z ${var+x} ]]; then echo unset; elif [[ -z $var ]]; then echo empty; else echo not empty; fi
empty
$ var=foo
$ if [[ -z ${var+x} ]]; then echo unset; elif [[ -z $var ]]; then echo empty; else echo not empty; fi
not empty
```

You'll never get "emptyvar has length 0" -- that's what "empty" is